# Reference request: connectedness of the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

We know that a connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has connected complement if its boundary is connected. Is there a reference for this result and results related to this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The open unit disk and its boundary are connected, but the complement is not?!

Comment: You should tell us in which ambient space your set is contained. In  $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: We know no such thing.  The unit disk is connected snd has a connect boundary and its complement is unbounded.

Comment: Sorry! I rewrote the question!

Comment: I don't know what your original question was that the previous comments refer to, but as stated it's still false. The unit ball is a counterexample in all dimensions other than $n=1$, where the statement is also false for other relatively basic reasons.